# heading like format without starting a subsection, without warning

Tags: line-breaking

I want to realize this effect:

```latex
\textbf{Settings.}\\
\(z\)-axis states: \(\ket{\uparrow}, \ket{\downarrow}\).\\
```

However this code generates a warning `Underfull \hbox`. I also read that many people say it is almost always **not wise** to use `\\` for new line. So how do I do this correctly, without using `\section{Settings}`, avoiding any error?

Comment: Just skip a line and write `\noindent \(z\)-axis states: \(\ket{\uparrow}, \ket{\downarrow}\).`

Comment: Remove the double backslash after `\textbf{Settings.}`

Comment: It's the second ``\\`` that causes the warning, if followed by an empty line.